# Azure Policy: Tag defines if a resource can be moved/deployed to a specific location

Tags: json, azure

I am trying to block the resource creation/migration to another region than specific ones based on when a Tag (Tag Name is "test" and Tag Value is "Yes") with Azure Policies. Until now I got this, but when I assign it, it is still possible to create resources in another locations when the new resource has the specific Tag. Additionally, Azure tells me that the if "requires a source and an exists". Any ideas what is wrong?

```
    {
  "mode": "Indexed",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "AllOf": [
        {
          "field": "tags['test']",
          "exists": "true"
        },
        {
          "value": "tags['test']",
          "equals": "yes"
        },
        {
          "field": "location",
          "notIn": [
            "France Central",
            "France South",
            "North Europe",
            "West Europe"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "deny"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {}
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I found the answer:

```
{
  "if": {
    "AllOf": [
      {
        "field": "tags['test']",
        "exists": "true"
      },
      {
        "field": "tags['test']",
        "equals": "yes"
      },
      {
        "field": "location",
        "notIn": [
          "France Central",
          "France South",
          "North Europe",
          "West Europe"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "then": {
    "effect": "deny"
  }
}
```

Basically, the "value" word had to be a "Field" word.